# Chunked tokenization in huggingface has an arrow error

Tags: python, pyarrow, apache-arrow, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I'm following the code from [this video](https://youtu.be/8PmhEIXhBvI?t=86) at 1m25s, which shows:

```
def tokenize_and_chunk(texts):
  return tokenizer(
    texts["text"], truncation=True, max_length=context_length,
    return overflowing_tokens=True
  )

tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
  tokenize_and_chunk, batched=True, remove_columns=["text"]
)
```

Here's the error I get when I try to run this code:

```
model_name = "t5-base"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

context_length = 1000

def tokenize_and_chunk(texts):
    return tokenizer(
      texts["text"], truncation=True, max_length=context_length,
      return_overflowing_tokens=True,
  )

dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame([{"id": "123", "text": "Here are many words! "*5000}]))
```

Shows a fine data set:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['id', 'text'],
    num_rows: 1
})
```

Ok,let's run the tokenizer:

```
toknized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_and_chunk, batched=True, remove_columns=["text"])

 0%
0/1 [00:00<?, ?ba/s]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-d1216744e2ab> in <module>
----> 1 toknized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_and_chunk, batched=True, remove_columns=["text"])

ArrowInvalid: Column 1 named id expected length 5 but got length 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Dataset is containing not only "text" column but "id" column as well.
**Remove column "id" and run map function - all works now.**

Also, in Your video tutorial.
If You look into his example using "imdb" dataset (at 48th second), he is then removing column "label", leaving his dataset with only one column "text".

**EDIT**
To make Your dataset works without removing "id" before passing it to the map function, You have to then change `remove_columns=["text"]` into `remove_columns=["id", "text"]`